# Google maps transition

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an activity where there is a small panel containing a google map of a point of interest.

Now I want that when the user clicks the panel, it expands into full screen map (with actionbar) to be able to operate with it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above you can do this via [Shared Element Transition](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html). For example, like in [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition#1-enable-window-content-transitions) tutorial, you can use [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) shared via two Activities (e.g. `MainActivity` - where `MapView` is on small panel and `MapActivity` - where `MapView` takes full screen)

1. Enable Window Content Transitions: add `<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>` to your `styles.xml` file:

   ```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

       <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Assign a common transition name e.g. `"common_map"` by add `android:transitionName="common_map"` parameter to the both shared `MapView` in layouts of `MainActivity` and  `MapActivity`:

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="<your_package_name>.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:transitionName="common_map"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Small panel with map"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`activity_map.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="<your_package_name>.MapActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview_fullscreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionName="common_map"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

3. Start the `MapActivity` by specifying a bundle of shared `MapView` elements e.g. on "small panel" (`mPanelLayout`) click:

   `mPanelLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel);
   mPanelLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
               ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                       makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, (View) mMapView, "common_map");
               startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
           }
   });`

And that's it.

NB! You must forward on the following all `MapView` methods: `onCreate(Bundle), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(), onSaveInstanceState(), onLowMemory()` or use [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite#lifecycle) and forward only `onCreate()`.

Full source code:

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";
    static final LatLng KYIV = new LatLng(50.450311, 30.523730);

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapView mMapView;
    private RelativeLayout mPanelLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(KYIV)
                        .title("Kyiv"));
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(KYIV)
                        .zoom(12)
                        .build()));
            }
        });

        mPanelLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel);
        mPanelLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, (View) mMapView, "common_map");
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }

        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

`MapActivity.java`:

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey1";
    static final LatLng KYIV = new LatLng(50.450311, 30.523730);

    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        setTitle("Full screen");

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview_fullscreen);
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(KYIV)
                        .zoom(12)
                        .build()));
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(KYIV)
                        .title("Kyiv"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: MapView transition]

Also, you can customize transition animation (make it more smooth, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can put gmap layout in a `FrameLayout` and also add a transparent view to it set `onClick` to the transparent view and handle fullscreen